# How to secure admin specific area to specific role using SonataAdmin

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

I have a working SonataAdminBundle installation, meanings my admin is well secured and cannot be accessed by simple users.

```
- { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
```

I have created some admin sections in the backoffice.

But, I don't want all of these sections to be available to each admin users. To explain a little bit, my website will allow to build custom websites. So I don't want a website admin to be able to access all websites informations. So I need to restrict some parts of the admin to super admin only.

In order to do that, I tried to limit the access to one of the section to Super admin only

```
- { path: ^/admin/app/site/, role: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]}
```

Here is my role hierarchy

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDI
```

The problem is, if I create a new user with my super admin account and give him the ROLE_ADMIN. 
Then this user is still able to access my `admin/app/site/*` section so obviously it's not working and I can't figure it why.

EDIT: I have the feelings this can't be done without using ACL...but I don't really need ACL that much...

Comment: Did you log out and log in again after changing the role? Roles are saved inside the session and not updated while logged in.

Comment: Yes I did log. I always clear cache and log off after this kind of modification.